# How to use If statement in addCondition, YII

Tags: sql, yii

I have some conditions to hand on to my dataprovider. Now, my last condition I want only to take place only when the field "edit" is set to true -> In this case I want to check if the editConfirmed field 'editBevestigd' is set to true. If the 'edit' field is empty I don't want to add this last condition.

```
$criteria->addCondition('bevestigd = 1');
$criteria->addCondition('IF(edit = 1) editBevestigd = 1');
```

What is the best way to handle this. Can I do this in YII (problem here is that the record is not known yet). Or how do I write this in SQL (I know this last condition isn't right right now..)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i right understand what you want then you should use this condition:

`WHERE (edit = 1 AND editBevestigd = 1) OR edit = 0`

Thus, the condition becomes:

```
$criteria->addCondition('(edit = 1 AND editBevestigd = 1) OR edit = 0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that

```
//for php variable set or not
if($edit==1){
 $criteria->addCondition('editBevestigd=1');
}

//for column set or not
$criteria->addCondition('edit IS NOT NULL AND editBevestigd=1');
```